# How do I send http requests to a Unix socket?

Tags: http, curl, unix-socket

I have an nginx config that passes incoming requests to a local unix socket that's specifically listening for incoming requests

(If you're curious, this happens to be a Rails app running [puma](https://puma.io/), but the question is generally applicable)

```
upstream app {
  server unix:/var/www/example.com/volumes/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

  listen              443 ssl;
  server_name         example.com;

  # Forward incoming requests to the socket
  location @app {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  # ...
}
```

If I am logged into the local machine where this app is running, **how do I send http requests to this Unix socket?**

I can't seem to do -

```
curl unix://%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fexample.com%2Fvolumes%2Ftmp%2Fsockets%2Fpuma.sock
curl: (1) Protocol "unix" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Comment: Looks like this was answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/834307/can-curl-send-requests-to-sockets

Comment: obviously `unix://` is not a recognized URL scheme...